# Free docking controls that can be docked into third party app

Tags: c#, winforms, docking, dockpanel-suite

I have a application(not mine) that uses AxXtremeDockingPane by CodeJock to add dockable panels to the application.

AxXtremeDockingPane has a method called `AttachToWindow(int handle)` which when called will create a docking manger into the window with the handle supplied, which can be any application.

I was wondering if there are any other free/cheaper docking controls that will let you do the same thing?

What I am trying to do is, the main application(not mine) creates a docking manager in it's main window when the application runs but they made access to the AxXtremeDockingPane private meaning that I can not add my own panels to the main application window. The problem is if you try and make a new AxXtremeDockingPane and call `AttachToWindow(int handle)` using the handle to the main application or any child windows it throws a MemoryAccessViolation because there is already a docking manager there.

I would like to find another suite that can do the same thing, so I can create a new docking manager into the main window, so have AxXtremeDockingPane and {other control} in the main window.

Sorry bit hard to explain.

Does anyone know how I can do this, or know any tools that do.

Comment: https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

Answer (score 4):

I've never used it, but there is an open-source DockPanel suite on SourceForge here:

http://dockpanelsuite.com

It looks exactly like Visual Studio's DockPanel stuff based on the screenshots.

Comment: A month late, but I second the dock panel suite.  I've used it in numerous internal applications.

Comment: How do you start with it as the documentation makes no sense